# How to execute st_read function including multibyte character?

Tags: r, sf

how to execute st_read function including multibyte character?

```
library(sf)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
st_write(obj = nc, dsn = enc2utf8("データ"),layer = "nc", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
st_read(dsn = enc2utf8("データ"), layer = "nc")
```

Cannot open data source C:\Users*****\nc\データ
Error in CPL_read_ogr(dsn, layer, as.character(options), quiet, type,  :
  Open failed.

Comment: I would explore this with GDAL independently from R, first. For R help, consider the R-Sig-Geo mailing list, and the Issues board for sf itself.